# call extbase query function from another extension

Tags: typo3, extbase

I got one TYPO3 extbased based extension with the following Repository:

```
public function findSomething() {              
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $results = $query->execute();     
    return $results;
}
```

The call works from the same extension. No I got a second extension where i instanciate the first extension:

```
$repo = t3lib_div::makeInstance('the_first_Repository');
$item = $repo->findSomething();
```

But the Repository returns nothing (type=object with a bunch of useless data). No I rewrote the findSomething() function in the Repository to use the old fashioned DBAL Layer:

```
public function findSomething() {    
    $items = array();        
    $res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery('*','some_table');
    while($row = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $items[] = $row;
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Which works. What i got to do to use the extbase based query framework from my second extension?!

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Typical 8+ hours of programing problem -.-
I forgot to add the `persistence.storagePid` for the objects of the first extension.